# Optimised Macro to sort Column Order based on Headers

Tags: performance, emeditor

Any thoughts on how to sort very large multi-column data via a macro. So for example, sorting all the columns (or perhaps just the selected adjacent columns?) by A-Z, or 0-9, etc. Similar to the Current single Column sorting options.

Comment: I believe I understand your question, but can you clarify your question by writing an example?

Comment: Do you want to sort columns by looking at the first row of each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to sort all columns by looking at the first row of each column, I wrote a macro:

```
function SortOneColumn()
{
    count = document.GetColumns();
    arr = new Array(count);
    for( i = 0; i < count; ++i ) {
        s = document.GetCell( 1, i + 1, eeCellIncludeNone );
        arr[i] = { name: s, col: i };
    }
    arr.sort( function( a, b ) {
      var nameA = a.name.toLowerCase();
      var nameB = b.name.toLowerCase();
      if( nameA < nameB ) {
        return -1;
      }
      if( nameA > nameB ) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });

    bSorted = false;
    for( i = 0; i < count; ++i ) {
        if( arr[i].col != i ) {
            document.MoveColumn( arr[i].col + 1, arr[i].col + 1, i + 1 );
            bSorted = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return bSorted;
}

while( SortOneColumn() );
```

There is a potential for optimizing the macro even further, so please let me know if this is not fast enough.

To run this, save this code as, for instance, `SortColumns.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run SortColumns.jsee** in the **Macros** menu.

Comment: Thanks Yutaka - this works exactly as required (and seems quick enough). Maybe in a future version the optimised version could be a native menu option when the user Right-Clicks the top left area just above the ruler (so all columns are selected)  (something like Sort All Columns by Header)? Thanks again.